# fopen() Throws a warning

Tags: php, file

I have a script that calls `fopen()` to create a text file. On the first run of the script it throuws a warning:

`PHP Warning:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty`

As far as I can tell, this is because the file doesn't exist. I would like to get rid of the warning.

How should I create files with PHP. Is `fopen()` the only main option like the docs and all the other message beards say?

*Edit: Just to Clarify*

The file is created and written to correctly. It just throws a warning if the file doesn't exist.

*Edit: The code was in the comments, but I'll put it here.*

```
public function createFile($location = null, $file_name = null)
{
    if (null === $location){
        $location = $this->getFileLocation();
    }
    if (null === $file_name){
        $file_name = $this->getFileName();
    }

    $file_location = realpath($location . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name);

    if (!file_exists($file_location)) {
        $this->setFileHandle(fopen($file_location, 'a'));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As I've said, it works just fine, just throws a warning.

Comment: for creation fwrite() is there?

Comment: provide a file name? You can't just `$fh = fopen()`... fopen would not complain if the file didn't exist, unless you're opening it for reading only... a non-existen file would be created if you're opening for write/append.

Comment: @MarcB I don't just $fh = fopen. I use `fopen(file_location', 'w').

Comment: Show the actual lines from you `PHP` file where you're trying to create the file.

Comment: @stvcisco They're in the comments. I'll post to the main question.

Comment: Make sure `file_location` is actually set to something

Comment: @stvcisco It is, else it wouldn't write the file right? I just manually debugged my function, and everything works as it should. It only throws an error when the file doesn't exist, which creating the file is the purpose of `fopen`.

Comment: Well the warning seems to be complaining about 'filename' which is the first parameter to `fopen`. If you can print out the value of `filename` before the call, that might help narrow down what's actually happening. Also show the actual cut-and-pasted code. It can't be what you had in the comment above because it says `fopen(file_location','w')` which has an extra quote in it. Including how `file_location` is set would also help.

Comment: @stvcisco The code is in the question now. To my knowledge, it is supposed to complain about a filename to a file that doesn't exist. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the second argument to `fopen`, which indicates the mode of the file handle you're creating. Some modes will attempt to create the file if it doesn't exist, other modes will throw the error you mention. Also take a look at `file_put_contents`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

If this doesn't help, please provide a complete working code example.

Comment: `fopen($file_location, 'w')`, `fopen($file_location, 'x')`, and `fopen($file_location, 'x') `throw a warning.

Comment: As you've now been asked twice already, please provide more code. I can't debug a snippet.